# installing nokogiri error: unrecognized command line option "-Wdivision-by-zero"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

running `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'` on osx 10.9 mavericks

getting:

```
make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling html_document.c
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wdivision-by-zero"
make: *** [html_document.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Answer (score 5):

I met this error when I tried to install nokogiri `1.6.6.2` on Mac 10.9, here is how I fixed that:

```
CC=llvm-gcc gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.6.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

couldn't find anything on this error either when trying to gem install on a fresh rvm ruby 2.1.0 on osx 10.7.5, lion.

installing via homebrew as detailed on [nokogiri's home page](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html) worked for me.

gotta have your compiler working too (gcc for me).
takes a while to make the damn thing tho.
best of luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install libxml2 libxslt
brew link libxml2 libxslt
```

Then install libiconv from source:

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libiconv/libiconv-1.13.1.tar.gz
tar xvfz libiconv-1.13.1.tar.gz
cd libiconv-1.13.1
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1
make
sudo make install
```

Then (finally) install nokogiri:

```
gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/include/libxml2 
                        --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/lib 
                        --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.26 
                        --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/include 
                        --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/lib
```

Source: http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

Answer (score 0):

Running:

`open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg`

from the [Nokogiri installation documentation](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html) worked for me.